# Store number in part of byte, but not from start?

Tags: c++

I have a byte: **A**:0 **B**:0 **C**:0 **D**:0 **E**:0 **F**:0 **G**:0 **H**:0

I want to store a number from 0-31, the fastest way, using only the space of characters C, D, E, F, G.
In other words, I want to leave the bits 1 and 2 empty, use the bits 3-7 to store the number and have bit 8 empty.

I can set the n bit of a byte using `c |= 1 << n;` But I fail to understand how to make it start from pos 2?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried. StackOverflow is _not_ here to do your homework for you

Comment: This is not homework, I am trying to create a compression algorithm.

Comment: You may try with n + 2...

Comment: @Adriano: not sure I understand?

Comment: @Luka if you add 2 to n then you'll skip 2 LSB bits (if I did understand your question)

Comment: Okay, I see. Will this leave the last bit free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in the ASCII range for readable characters (32-126), you will not have the valid range in 5 bits to meet the required encoding.  For example:

```
~ (126)     = 01111110
(Your Mask) = 01111100
```

Thus, `~` (126) would be the same as `|` (124).

If you have somehow already adjusted your encoding and can be assured that you will only have data in the lower 5 bits, than you can simply use bitwise operations:

```
unsigned char a = your_data;
a = (a & 0x1F) << 2; // shift the lower 5 bits over 2 bits
```

Comment: If I want to store the 1st bit on the last bit of char a[0] and the remaining 4 on the first 4 bits of char a[1], how to do it?

Comment: @Luka Making sure I understand your question:  You want to have 2 `char`s where the first one holds bit 5 from `a` and the second holds bits 1-4?

Comment: char A got 8 bits. We take the 8th. char B got 8 bits. We take 1st, 2nd 3rd and 4th. We use those bits to store a 5 bit number.

Comment: So you want some `char c` that holds `a`'s 8th bit, and `b`'s 1-4th bits?

Comment: yes, exactly... I also want to set those bits, not only read them

Comment: If that is the case, it is simply:  `unsigned char c = ((a & 0x80) >> 1) | (b & 0x3C);`  Assuming bits 3-6 are the valid bits for `b`.  If that isn't the case, you add a bit-shift in there to move them to the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = theNumber
//Skip two bytes
a *= 4
//clean bytes 1,2 and 8 (124 in binary = 0111100)
a = a & 124
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are you doing there? I mean, why 131 and why 4?

Comment: Yes, already done :), changed &!131 for & 124 which is the same

Comment: The last line might be clearer as `a &= 0x7c`. It would be even nicer if C had binary literals: `0b01111100`. (gcc supports them as an extension, but I don't recommend using them if you care about your code's portability to other compilers.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Coming soon to a C++14 near you!

Comment: @sftrabbit: I missed the tag; I should have said C++, not C. (I know of no plans to add such a feature to C, and some C compiler vendors are much slower to adopt new standards than C++ vendors anyway.)